# How to create a "live" feed for two seperate Postgres Instances?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, database-administration

So I feel pretty confident inside of Postgres but I have an interesting problem in my opinion.

I have my local Postgres instance and a remote Postgres instance. My remote instance is read only as it is a production server. I need to be able to pull records and generate views/tables/reports/whatever.

How can I accomplish that?

Currently I am using dblink running every 15 Minutes pretty much resetting my local instance by dropping all objects and using pgAgent jobs to rebuild all objects ready for the next cycle. It is really labor intensive to make changes and even worse to troubleshoot.

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem. You need to generate views/tables/reports. So it seems to me that you don't update the database. If so... why don't you read directly from your production server ?

Comment: ... How would one do that?

Comment: how do you connect to your local postgres ? there's a "host" variable there right ? it should read "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" because you're connecting to your machine. Just put the IP of your production server, along with user/password and you'll connect to it. One thing to remind is that your production server must allow connections from the outside. Check the pg_hba.conf on your server and/or firewall rules.

Comment: My "reporting" (local) server allows network connections so most of the time I am connecting remotely to manage but there is a localhost option which is used when I am on the actual server.

Since the production server is read only I connect to it, (like showing inside of PGadmin) and I can query from it, view data, dblink of course) but I can't get a live feed from it.

Comment: I think I don't made myself clear. Could you please show me the code where you connect to postgreSQL please ?

Comment: so you want the sensitive data redacted pg_hba file?

Comment: I'm not talking about pg_gba fila. I want to see the code you use to connect to postgreSQL. Are you using a tool, programming langage, what ? where do you put the host, user and password ? please change the sensitive data as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eventual solution was to make views through dblink. it is slightly clunky but the speed increase is substantial and worth the more restrictive coding requirements for the connection.